# Wordpress Email subscribtion?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have Wordpress blog site and I wanted the users to enter their email to subscribe to my blog.If i add any new post in the blog the subscriber should to get the email alerts.

```
I know this is possible since I have seen in many blogs.

If anyone know how to implement this in Wordpress, let me know.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few good options for implementing an email subscription service for your WordPress blog.  (I am assuming you are using the self hosted WordPress and not WordPress.com)

[Google FeedBurner](http://feedburner.google.com) gives you the most options and works great with WordPress.

To set up email subscriptions click the publicize tab in the FeedBurner settings:

[image]

To seamlessly integrate with FeedBurner you will need to add a redirect to your .htaccess file or you can use a [plugin to do this for you](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedburner-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

Also aweber.com has a plugin that integrates with Feedburner and also provides additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin called "Email capture wordpress plugin" which will be populated when unique user came to your site.This plugin asking for news latter subscription.

Once user subscribe to news latter you can send email to multiple users.Admin also can delete email users.

You can get more from and screenshort from [here...](http://www.my-php-scripts.net/index.php/Wordpress/email-capture-wordpress-plugin-advanced-php.html)